# Switching tab in UITabbar is so slow

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller, uitabbar

I have 5 tabs in UITabbar when I switching 1 > 2 on first time, It slow because in 2 have so much complex view and setup on viewDidLoad().

How can I make it faster or better ? Can I preload 2 when I open 1 ? or Can I show loading indicator when it loading view ?

Answer (score 1):

There is too little context about you problem. The only thing which I can recomend you is to research problem using "Time profiler" instrument in XCode

(For XCode 12.5)
**Press XCode -> Open Developer Tool -> Instruments**

[image]

**Then. Press "Time Profiler"**

[image]

**For ViewController with such code**

```
import UIKit

class DelayViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var i = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        while i < 100000000 {
            print("i is \(i)")
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

**We can see in "Time profiler" how much time takes print method**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have too much tasks running on main queue. You should be only doing updating of UI on main queue. Are you fetching something from database, downloading pictures etc. in the method  `DispatchQueue.main.async  { }` ? If yes, try fetching these things from database on some other queue (for example `DispatchQueue.global`). You can also use `UIActivityIndicator`  until your setup is done, and then update it on main queue.